# How to make 1 to 1 relationship in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have 2 entities in my project. First is Route entity and second one is Address.
Route has starting address as well as ending address.

```
Route:
Name
startingAddress
endingAddress

Address:
street
streetNumber
country
```

Relationship should be 1 to 1. One route has one starting address, and one starting address has one route. The problem is that I also use attribute endingAddress, which also leads to Address. I have created first relationship from Route(startingAddress) to Address, but I can't create second one, because the name is already used.

How can I create relationship between those two? Should I just create optional relationship with different name?

Comment: What do you mean the name is already used? There should be no problem creating 2 relationships between 2 entities.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i created relationship with name "route" in my Address entity. Destination is route Entity, but I need to create second one for endAddress too. I can't use the same name for the relationship and I don't want to use "optional values". With optionals Address entity would have relation for start or for end address.

Comment: So call it something different then, routeStart and routeEnd for instance.

Comment: Yea but then i will have to deal with optional relationships. I don't want to use this.

Comment: I just tried in Xcode and I don't understand your claim that one has to be optional. It makes no sense.

Comment: I guess you could conceivably use a model where none of the relationships has an inverse, and take on the responsibility for ensuring referential integrity yourself, rather than letting CoreData do it for you.  But I really don’t recommend it.  So I think “optional relationships” might be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that there are no inverse relationships for startingAddress and endingAddress on Address. It might be best to model Address (route) as many-to-one to Route (addresses) then sort the addresses and use array first and last properties to determine starting and ending addresses.

Comment: I already thought about that idea, but I would like to stick with 1-to-1 relationship.